# CSS Selector for 'default' button in a javafx Alert?

Tags: java, javafx-8

in javafx, does anyone know the css selector for the color of the "default" button in an alert? The "Yes" button in light blue here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base color for a default button is set to the looked-up color `-fx-default-button`:

```css
.button:default {
    -fx-base: -fx-default-button;
}
```

which defaults to the light blue in your screenshot:

```css
.root {

    /* ... */

    -fx-default-button: #ABD8ED;

    /* ... */
}
```

(Code snippets from modena.css [source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9/rt/file/c734b008e3e8/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css).)

So you can just change the value of `-fx-default-button` on your root element.